# Complex $resource url template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

So I want to call REST service with the following URL patterns:
1.domain.com/service.svc/action1/sessionid/objectid
2.domain.com/service.svc/action2/sessionid/objectid/objectid2
3.domain.com/service.svc/action3/sessionid/objectid
4.domain.com/service.svc/action4/sessionid/objectid/objectid3/objectid4
5.domain.com/service.svc/action5/sessionid/objectid4/objectid5/objectid6/objectid2

and I ended up with this resource object:

```
 var object = $resource('domain.com/service.svc/:actionName/:sessionId/:objectid:objectid4/
:objectid2:objectid3:objectid5/:objectid4:objectid6/:objectid2:', {}, {});
```

And I can call:

```
object.get({
    'action1': action1,
    'sessionid': sessinId,
    'objectid': objectid
})
```

I see the problem here with the URL template, it looks cumbersome to read.The second problem is that URL number 2 expects objectid2 in one location in URL, and then URL number 5 expects the same parameter at the end of url.This breaks URL template, so I had to rename one of the  them.Is there a better solution for this particular problem, and what are the best practices regarding REST services with these complex URI's ?

Comment: Your service does not have very RESTful URLs! Maybe it would be easier to match in separate URI templates?

Comment: You mean to create more $resource objects with different URL templates ?